# Developing Heatmap using Next.js and react-leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, heat-map, react

For a research project, I was tasked to develop a GIS very similar to https://cwfis.cfs.nrcan.gc.ca/interactive-map.  This is the first time I will develop a GIS-related web application and **I do not know where to start**.  I have been researching about leaflet/react-leaflet and geojson. One of my searches also showed react-leaflet-heatmap-layer-v3 (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-leaflet-heatmap-layer-v3).  Unfortunately, it does not work in the current version of Next.js 13.

Is there an alternative?

Or is there a better approach to fetch/process/display data? Currently, I was able to display different GeoJSON data/files but I am not sure if this is the right way. The values will be coming from a database, should I convert it to GeoJSON data then display it?

Again, the project is the same as the Canadian Wildland Fire Information System but for a different country. I am limited to using free resources.

```
// Map.js
'use client'
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, GeoJSON } from 'react-leaflet';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';

function Map(props) {
  const { center, zoom, geojsonData } = props;
  const [map, setMap] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (map && geojsonData) {
        setInterval(function () {
        map.invalidateSize();
      }, 100);
    }
  }, [map]);

  return (
    <MapContainer center={center} zoom={zoom} style={{ height: '100vh', width: '100%' }} whenCreated={setMap}>
      <TileLayer
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        attribution='© <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      />
      { geojsonData && <GeoJSON key={JSON.stringify(geojsonData)} data={geojsonData} /> }
      
    </MapContainer>
  );
}

export default Map;
```